# Creating Columns for Hour of Day and date based on datetime column

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, datetime

How can I create a new column that has the day only, and hour of day only based of a column that has a datetime timestamp?

DF has column such as:

```
   Timestamp
2019-05-31 21:11:43 
2018-11-21 18:01:00 
2017-11-21 22:01:04 
2020-04-15 11:01:00 
2017-04-20 04:00:33
```

I want two new columns that look like below:

```
   Day      | Hour of Day
2019-05-31     21:00
2018-11-21     18:00
2017-11-21     22:00    
2020-04-15     11:00    
2017-04-20     04:00
```

I tried something like below but it only gives me a # for hour of day,

```
df['hour'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Timestamp'], format='%H:%M:%S').dt.hour
```

*where output would be 9 for 9:32:00 which isnt what I want to calculate*

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by "day", day of month? Also, do you want to round the time to the nearest hour or just floor it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try `dt.strftime(format+string)`

```
df['hour'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Timestamp']).dt.strftime("%H"+":00")
```

Following your comments below. Lets Try use `df.assign` and extract `hour` and `date` separately

```
df=df.assign(hour=pd.to_datetime(df['Timestamp']).dt.strftime("%H"+":00"), Day=pd.to_datetime(df['Timestamp']).dt.date)
```

Comment: thnx. but how can I alter so I have the day column as well?

Comment: Yes, lets try `df=df.assign(hour=pd.to_datetime(df['Timestamp']).dt.strftime("%H"+":00"), Day=pd.to_datetime(df['Timestamp']).dt.date)`

Answer (score 0):

You could convert time to string and then just select substrings by index.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Timestamp': ['2019-05-31 21:11:43', '2018-11-21 18:01:00', 
                             '2017-11-21 22:01:04', '2020-04-15 11:01:00', 
                             '2017-04-20 04:00:33']})
df['Day'], df['Hour of Day'] = zip(*df.Timestamp.apply(lambda x: [str(x)[:10], str(x)[11:13]+':00']))
```